# Need to disable SSL certificate verification with RestSharp

Tags: vb.net, certificate, restsharp

I have disabled SSL certificate verification using the Postman tool and sent a post request with 4 parameters. This method returns the correct response but I cannot seem to replicate this using VB.Net. I am using RestSharp to connect to a RESTful API and I am setting the certification validation callback to a functio that always returns true using ServicePointManager, but my problem still persists:

```
Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(sender As Object, certification As X509Certificate, 
                    chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function

Public Function SendRequest() As Boolean

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications)

    Dim client = New RestClient(TokenEndPoint) 'A basic URI endpoint
    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    request.AddParameter("scope", "write")
    request.AddParameter("client_id", "client-app")
    request.AddParameter("client_secret", "secret")

    response = client.Execute(request)
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
End Function
```

I always get:

```
{"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}
```

As the response. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try messing with the value of ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.  It may be needing TLS.

Comment: @NoAlias Thank you. I had to use: 

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

And then it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked.  I didn't want to post it as an answer based on speculation, but since you confirmed it worked I added one that is more thorough than the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is often a sign that the [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) needs to be changed.  You can try TLS.  Note that this setting is universal, so everything will be TLS at that point unless you change it to SSL.